# Dividing power law distribution

Tags: networks, power-law

Most of the social communities follows power law distribution. I have data for 3 communities from stackexchange websites. Number of posts , answers by  users follow the power law distribution. There are methods available to estimate Xmin using Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) statistic http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1062v2.pdf

Is there a way to divide the power law distribution into three categories on the basis of number of posts/ answers. I want to cut a community power distribution into three categories .

1. Users having high number of posts/answers
2. Users having intermediate number of posts
3. Users having minimum number of posts.

Comment: You should consider a better title.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, perhaps a concrete example would help.